# Please burninate [website]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514079/people-you-may-know-emails) is pretty good prima-facia evidence that [website](/questions/tagged/website) is just facilitating the deposition of crap.

Comment: While `website` appears useful at first glance, any question which is about web development should have other tags which would imply as such (e.g. `pho`, `sql`, `asp.net`, etc.).

Comment: Tags as broad as [tag:website] should be eliminated. It is disorganized and promotes off-topic questions.

Comment: Wow. Did I really misspell "php"? I'm off my spllign today.

Comment: Some of these questions make me wish I had a real flamethrower.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Delete doesn't do it for you? Want me to make a userscript that changes `delete` into `burninate`?

Comment: Maybe we should burn [webpage] too.